# What is Causing my Graphics to Fail?

Tags: graphics, vlc

Occasionally when I'm viewing a program through VLC and I maximize it to full screen it will distort the video so I can only hear audio. Then when I minimize again it will only work at some resolutions but most of the time the video doesn't work. This is solved by a reboot but this problem has become a regular occurrence now. I've tried running VLC from a console but I experience unhelpful error messages or other output when it happens. Does anyone have any ideas on how I might go about solving this?

Here is what the video looks like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rEaLS.jpg

I'm currently using AMD/ATI graphical drivers. Could that have anything to do with it? The issue has persisted for months now.